# Как дать первому элементу placeholder разный стиль?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```css
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
 font-size: 14px;

}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
 font-weight: bolder;
}
::-moz-placeholder  {
 font-size:14px; /* Firefox 19+ */
}
:-moz-placeholder  {
 font-size: 14px; /* Firefox 18- */
}
```

```html
<input type=text placeholder="Canada (235 hotels)....">
```

Есть `placeholder` в котором внутри есть текст нужно чтобы первый текст был жирным а второй который в кавычках простым.Уже пробовал через `first-line` но не помогло.Есть ли какой нибудь алтернатива или может я делаю что нибудь неправильно?Менять `html` тег невозможно так как этот `input` внутри библиотеки `selectize.js` поэтому трогать `html` мы не можем

Comment: Придется отказаться от  placeholder и  в место него использовать другие элементы и с помощью js для имитации placeholder

Comment: @Visman нет не дубликат.

Comment: @Air тут у меня select option поэтому отказаться никак не могу

Comment: Тогда Опиши вопрос более подробно, что бы можно было дать белее объективный ответ... Хотя на данном моменте не понимаю, почему ты не можешь использовать   вариант который я описал

Comment: @Избытоксусликов, дубликат. Это утверждение доказывает данный вам ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', function() {
  if (document.querySelector('input').value.length == 0) {
    document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML = 'Canada';
  } else {
    document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML = ''; 
  }
})
```

```css
.body {
  position:relative;
}
.click_hidden_text {
  position:absolute;
  left:60px;
  opacity:0.6;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
 font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<span class="click_hidden_text">(235 hotels)</span>
<input type="text" placeholder="canada">
```

Comment: спасибо большое за ответ но я изменил вопрос добавил что менять html мы не можем так как используется сторонная библиотека moment.js

Comment: Вот по этому никогда не использую сторонние библиотеки.... Никогда не добьешься того, что именно тебе надо)))

Comment: да но лень же писать с нулья вообще :)

Comment: Я наверное дурак, раз мне не лень))))

Comment: ты великий человек.))) может поможешь я почти сделал https://jsfiddle.net/Cheapskate/uy4edeLg/

Comment: посмотри ответ...  и объясни на кой тебе длина placeholder в твоем примере...  я html css взял твой а js оставил свой, зачем такие сложности?

Comment: спасибо огромное я понял суть.И в чем там сложность я не понял ?

Comment: Во-первых,  я не больше твоего знаю JS..  Я еще не волшебник, я только учусь..))  Во-вторых просто не понял зачем тебе это, может там есть смысл о котором я не знаю? А если нет ни какого смысла, просто чем проще код, тем лучше на мой взгляд...

Comment: аа понятно :) Но на мой взгляд чем сложный кодь тем ты быстро учишсья и понимаешь все аспекты языка и добавляешь их в свой арсенал.

Comment: Ну вот во время тренировки я усложняю все... И руку набиваю, кручу перекручиваю...  А в рабочем чем проще тем лучше на мой взгляд...